# Проблема с загрузочной флешкой Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем доброго времени суток

Создал загрузочную флешку и при установке получаю следующую картину [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал эту же флешку на другом пк- все работает прекрасно

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста

Comment: Это ведь артефакты. Скорее всего проблема в видеоядре или видеокарте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил в параметры запуска nomodeset - заработало